# Problems Deploying web application to iis

Tags: iis, webmatrix

Built a web application with webmatrix, try to deploy locally to iis 5.1 for testing purposes so i added it to my wwwroot folder didnt work then i created a virtual directory. the home page works with this but my login created with web helper doesnt work...when i click login all i see is the browser sending login? and nothing happens....and my web deploy that i installed doesnt work either so i can deploy the site with dependencies to iis... also can it be deployed to windows server2003....any hints would be appreciated...
.

Comment: solved it...all i had to do was add .cshtm to the call back (login?) of the login page..

Answer (score 1):

I am using Webmatrix3 and my web server is Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7. I just copy and paste my entire project directory from my local machine up to the IIS inetpub/wwroot directory. Then from within IIS7 I right click that directory (which is now in the tree under sites) and select "Convert to Application". Works every time.

I also had to add this to my Web.config to make it work in I.E. because of the forced compatibility mode issue:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
     <clear />
     <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
   </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks Thomas Fonseca think i may migrate to webmatrix 3...sounds more simple.