# Page does not load after I migrated the database from SQL CE to SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, webmatrix, migrate

I am running into an issue. I have developed a site in webmatrix with SQL server compact edition. My site is ready and I can see it run without any issue in my PC. However, I ran into an issue after migrating the database to SQL server. Migration finished successfully and I can see all my tables, data in the migrated database. But I can not run the page anymore. In IE browser, it gives me error `Page cannot be displayed`. (In other browsers it just tries to load indefinitely).
I don't know what is the issue. If I remove the migrated database file(.mdf) and put the .sdf back in APP_DATA folder and connect it in database workspace, my site starts working again.
Note: I can see a connection string added to web.config file when migration is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you can connect to the migrated database from within SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS).  Your connection string in the web.config file needs to be correct and should look something like:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="Server=SERVER01;Database=mydatabase;Uid=user;Pwd=password" name="somename" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
 </connectionStrings>
```

After logging in through SSMS you will know what the settings should be. I hope this helps you.

Comment: This thread may also be helpful as it relates to deploying web matrix apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462875/problems-deploying-web-application-to-iis/16471868#16471868

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, thanks for your reply. Glad to let you know that issue has been resolved. The issue was regarding the sql server version. Basically I had SQL commands like "fetch first n rows only" etc. Now, this is not supported in SQL 2008. My migrated database was in 2008. When I imported the data into SQL 2012 database, it started working now.